# sequelize client.uuid, what is it and what effect does it have?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have an app that uses breeze-sequelize which can be found here:

http://breeze.github.io/doc-node-sequelize/

Basically it generates sequelize models/queries from breeze models/queries.
My question is:

Every time I execute a Insert, Update or Delete I see something like the following:

```
Executing (1b4b53e2-fca8-4b8d-9dd8-fee248b08e82): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (1b4b53e2-fca8-4b8d-9dd8-fee248b08e82): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
Executing (1b4b53e2-fca8-4b8d-9dd8-fee248b08e82): SET autocommit = 1;
Executing (default): UPDATE "v_account" SET "name"='PREMIER3' WHERE "account_pkey" = '8'
Executing (1b4b53e2-fca8-4b8d-9dd8-fee248b08e82): COMMIT;
```

where the only line that does not have the wierd alphanumeric string in the parentheses is the actual CRUD line. I was curious as to what was going on and so I went through the code and noticed that the weird string is actually the client.uuid. I am wondering what this uuid is, what effect it has, why it is not in the CRUD line and what effect that has as well?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[A UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (sometimes called a GUID*) is

> an identifier standard used in software construction. A UUID is simply a 128-bit value. The meaning of each bit is defined by any of several variants.
>
> For human-readable display, many systems use a canonical format using hexadecimal text with inserted hyphen characters. For example:

```
de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014
```

Essentially, its a unique ID being generated for you, to track transaction. Sequelize [names your transaction](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/transactions/), and a UUID is as close to guaranteed as you can get for a unique name. Its protecting you from transaction name collisions.

*Yes, I know there are minor distinctions between these two

Comment: Do you know what effect there is by not having the transaction name for the update line? Is it still happening in the same transaction?